# SQL Server 2016 SP 1 on HP 3PAR environment causes weird head blocker

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, storage

My client is on HP 3PAR hardware. Three servers are on different geographical locations, connected with a 40 gbit fibre connection. The SAN is SSD only, the machines have lots of cores.

The ETL process starts a single select query joining 2 tables. The execution plan shows the use of a non-clustered index combined with a heap scan for both tables.

This simple query becomes a head blocker for all other following queries, even those that are referencing completely different tables.

My first guess is that something with the 3PAR could be involved, but I'm not really sure. Besides that, it's really weird that a

```
select a.[value] from table a, inner join table b where table a.column = 12345
```

manages to block

```
update table c set column a = [value].
```

AFAIK there are no lock hints.

There are no triggers of foreign keys on the used tables. There are no functions or other creative extra's on the database.

I'm wondering if the HP 3PAR failover can in some way cause a query to lock a database or table or data partition or HOBT.
Any thoughts? If more info is needed, let me know.

**== Edit 12/28/2017**
Answered the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're troubleshooting a blocking chain happening live, start with [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/downloads/):

```
sp_WhoIsActive @get_locks = 1
```

There's a blocked-by column that shows you who's blocking who. The lead blocker won't have anyone in their blocked-by column.

Once you've found the lead blocker, click on the locks column - it's an XML field that expands to show you the full list of locks held by that session.

It could be that the select is part of a longer transaction (there's also an open transactions column), or that the select isn't really what's blocking.

Your best bet for getting specific, actionable advice here would be to post a picture of the sp_WhoIsActive output, including the blocking columns, and then the contents of the XML for the locks.

Comment: Thank you Brent! One additional question. The issue usually happens at night when the DBA'er on call just kills the headblocker as shown in the Activity Monitor. This unfreezes all the processes but makes it so much harder to find the root cause. Can i execute the sp_WhoIsActive in a job and log the results to a table for later use or will i miss out on the most juicy and interesting details?

Comment: After reading the manual.....  :) I've added a few parameters. This is the scripts that runs every 5 minutes to catch the blocking processes:
    EXEC sp_WhoIsActive 
  get_locks = 1
 , destination_table = 'DW_WHOISACTIVE'
 , get_plans = 1
 , get_transaction_info = 1
 , find_block_leaders = 1
(removed the @ because it references users :))

Answer (score 2):

If your SAN replication is set to synchronous, depending on the connection between boxes, that can have a measurable performance impact. The best way to measure it would be to benchmark the storage with and without synchronous replication.
I've also seen issues with deduplication on a full SSD 3PAR but that was a bug in the firmware that has since been fixed.

That being said, storage latency will not *cause* blocking in SQL Server by itself. It can, however make your transactions run for longer and as a consequence your locks (which are held by SQL Server, not the SAN) can be held for a longer period of time.

Since you are stating that the sites are in different geo-locations synchronous replication probably isn't your best option (IIRC it requires a max latency of 2ms between boxes). 3PAR offers 3 other methods of replication which might suit you better

- Asynchronous Periodic: Lets you configure the frequency and has a RPO of the configured frequency (typically a few minutes)
- Async Streaming: A new snapshot is taken as soon as the previous one is committed, typically has an RPO of a few seconds.
- SLD Sync Long Distance: requires 3 datacenters but could achieve an RPO of 0 by combining synchronous and asynchronous

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation! I will take this to the SAN admins who know way more about this than i do. But maybe this will set them on the right course to some explanation or fix.

Answer (score 0):

After using the sp_WhoIsActive (Thanks @brent-ozar) I've been able to move on to the next step.

Here's the executionplan of the blocking query:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy7rYfGXG

And this is the lock XML:

```
<Database name="DS4_P_Productie">
  <Locks>
    <Lock request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
  </Locks>
  <Objects>
    <Object name="AL_STATISTICS" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="IX" request_status="WAIT" 
request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
    <Object name="AL_VERSION" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="KEY" 
index_name="PK__AL_VERSI__D9C1FA015BCBE3FC" request_mode="X" 
request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="IX" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
    <Lock resource_type="PAGE" page_type="*" index_name="PK__AL_VERSI__D9C1FA015BCBE3FC" request_mode="IX" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
  </Locks>
</Object>
 </Objects>
</Database>
```

Keen readers will notice a discrepancy between the name of the index updates (AL_STAT_INDX2 and AL_STAT_INDX1) and another index (PK_AL_VERSI_..). The latter index lives on the AL_VERSION table, a table not even referenced in the query.

This table is used as well, but earlier:

```
<?query --
UPDATE "AL_STATISTICS" SET "KEY2" = 194462   WHERE "OBJECT_KEY" = -1
--?>
```

This query (with different KEY2 values) is executed repeatedly. Between executions of this update, there are various inserts into the AL_STATISTICS table.

So, on to further investigations. The source of the transactions is an ETL process. Wrong, **Two** ETL processes. Starting at exactly the same second. What happens next is that both processes want to access the tables. Most of the time this is no problem, unless either a read or write is just to slow. That's the point the serious blocking begins. One of the ETL processes runs every 5 minutes, the other every 15. You can guess what happens when the block originates around midnight and the first checks are around 7 in the morning.

Solution. Again, keen reader have seen this, there are no clustered indexes. After adding a clustered index on the statistics table the locks disappeared like the support for Brexit after the implications became clear.

To put the last remark in perspective, before the index, the sp_whoisactive table logged about 700 entries for 1 database in 5 days. In the last 3 days, only 6 entries were added.

So, one more step up the learning curve!